# What is the graph that corresponds to $Q'_8$ generalized quadrangle ? Could you please explain this in plain english?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

In [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166218X9290160C/1-s2.0-0166218X9290160C-main.pdf?_tid=2bf0c384-519f-11e5-ace5-00000aacb361&acdnat=1441218158_61f1d94a24c6a70b2576831acaae537f) paper a table about large graphs with given degree and diameter graphs is shown:

[image]

I would like to know what the adjacency list of the graph denoted by:

[image]

in the table above is.

Could you please explain how I can get that adjacency list of $Q'_8$?

The paper says that :

[image]

and

[image].

So $Q_8$ is the incidence graph of the regular generalised quadrangle and $Q'_8$ is the quotient of this. The problem is that I only understand the words "the", "so", "and", "is", "of" and "this" from the previous sentence.

What is the incidence graph of a regular generalized quadrangle ?

Is this incidence graph bipartite ? If yes, why ?

What is the quotient of that ?

How can I get the actual graph based on the above sentence ?

Is Mathematica a good tool for this task?

Comment: Mathematica does have GraphData[{"GeneralizedQuadrangle", {2, 2}}]  and other quadrangles.  But GraphData[585] is empty, it doesn't have this particular graph.  Graphs with 100+ vertices are typically messy, so it's better to look at the smaller graphs first.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I have a look ! I think the graph I am looking for is the quotient graph of the incidence graph of the regular generalized quadrangle, so I need to get the 8,8 (I assume) generalized quadrangle incidence graph and then take the quotient of that. According to wikipedia, the generalized quadrangle incidence graph has diameter 4, but $Q'_8$ has diameter 3, so taking the quotient should reduces the diameter to 3.

Comment: @MorganRodgers : Here is ref [9] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669885800433 it should be freely available. I can read it without paying.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Many thanks. I am trying to use this graph to create an educational tool.

Answer (score 3):

A Finite Generalized Quadrangle (FGQ) is an incidence structure $\mathcal{S}$ where we have *points*, *lines* (finite sets), and *incidence relation* satisfying:

1. Any two points lie on at most one line
2. Any two lines meet in at most one point
3. If $\ell$ is a line and $P$ is a point not incident with $\ell$, then there is a unique line $m$ on $P$ intersecting $\ell$.

So this is a *partial linear space* containing *no triangles*.  The Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quadrangle) is actually super nice, Bill Cherowitzo works hard on the finite geometry pages.

Now the most studied examples of generalized quadrangles are the *classical* examples, these are defined by certain types of nondegenerate sesquilinear forms on a vector space over a finite field.  Your example, given as $Q_{8}$, is commonly known as $W(8)$, obtained from a nondegenerate alternating bilinear form on the projective space $\mathrm{PG}(3,8)$ (defined by a four dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{8}$).

Two important graphs related to these objects are the *point collinearity graph* (which are strongly regular) and the *incidence graph*, bipartite with parts corresponding to points and lines. The incidence graph of a FGQ is another important structure, it has diameter four and girth eight.

Okay, now for your important questions: I don't know what they are taking the quotient by, so I can't help there.  I would program it in Magma, but that's my personal preference for working with a bilinear form over a finite field.  Your best bet is probably to capitalize on the hard work of Eric Moorhouse, who has the data related to the quadrangle [here](http://www.uwyo.edu/moorhouse/pub/genpoly/) (it is $W(8)$, having order $(8,8)$).

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks Morgan ! I look up reference [9].

Answer (score 2):

The most useful page I know of is [degree-diameter table](http://maite71.upc.es/grup_de_grafs/table_g.html/), which actually has pictures of many of the graphs.

The requested graph is described in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669802905810) --  C. Delorme and J. Gómez, Some New Large Compound Graphs, European Journal of Combinatorics, Volume 23, Issue 5, July 2002, Pages 539–547.

But take a look at the first link.  Even when the construction is given, figuring it out can be a murky process.  The best describer of complex graphs that I know of is [Brouwer](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will read the paper. The problem with that table is that unfortunately it does not have the adjacency list for this particular graph, hence my question. I hope I will be wiser after reading the mentioned paper from 2002.